# Wordpress how to calculate a value for a user and update related custom meta field

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, elementor, usermetadata

I have created a front-end form on Wordpress using `Elementor Pro`, and it is successfully updating the user meta of the logged in user when submitted.

I would now like to calculate a separate custom meta field, using the values that were submitted in the form.

In other words: when a user submits a value for custom field `straight_speed`, I would like to automatically calculate the `straight_speed_percent` using the value just entered, and save it against the user.

For now, the calculation for `straight_speed_percent` can just be `straight_speed` multiplied by 100.

(The custom field for `straight_speed_percent` has already been created).

Initially a value will need to be added for `straight_speed_percent`, but if the form is resubmitted and `straight_speed` is changed, I would like the value to be updated.

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user->ID;

$straight_speed = get_user_meta ('straight_speed', $current_user);

$straight_acceleration_percent_value  = $straight_speed * '100';

update_user_meta( $current_user, 'straight_acceleration_percent', '$straight_acceleration_percent_value' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some syntax and logical errors in your code!

- When you use `get_user_meta` you would need to use `$current_user->ID` and the `meta key`. [Read the docs for more details](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)!
- When you save `$straight_speed` variable to the database it's going to be saved as a text string, so when you get it back from database, convert it to an integer and then do the multiplication!
- Also you have extra quotations around your `$straight_acceleration_percent_value` variable when you're trying to update the value which is incorrect!

Use the following snippet:

```php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$straight_speed = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'straight_speed', true);

if ($straight_speed) {

  $straight_acceleration_percent_value  = (int)$straight_speed * 100;

  update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'straight_speed_percent', $straight_acceleration_percent_value);

}
```

This answer has been tested and works fine! Let me know if it works for you too!

Comment: Hi Ruvee. My apologies, I should have spotted the error. I was actually unaware of the text string issue - thanks for educating me. The code works perfectly. Thank you for the help.